# What is the logic behind "вялотекущая" attachable to an illness but not to a river?

Tags: semantics

In my understanding, "вялотекущая" means having a slow flux. This you would literally associate with rather with a river, but no -

1. вялотекущая шизофрения - ОK
2. вялотекущая река - NOT OK

Why? I understand that language can be quite irrational, but my question is - maybe in this special case there is indeed some crazy logic behind these cases?

Comment: Who down votes stuff like this? It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @VCH250 I've made myself quite an alibi, haven't I? Well, the passive-aggressiveness does seep through admittedly, but I tried as much as I could to compartmentalise. "Crazy logic."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ever heard of wholes being greater than the sums of their parts? Crazy, huh?

**Вялотекущая** is not the same as **вяло текущая**. The former is a medical term and was coined (or, if you like, glued together) as such. **Вяло текущая река** is fine.

Comment: _"Вяло текущая река"_ - formally the phrase is valid, but actually its meaning isn't. Not sure I'm right, but I think it wouldn't be very good to say "lazy river" in English?

Comment: @Qwertiy For what it's worth, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_river

Comment: Anyway, it's not about water speed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you will say `Вяло текущая река` in the context of river, say, standing on the bank of river - your friends may consider you to be a witty person. I think i should remember this for a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

1) Мы увлеклись игрой. Время текло незаметно.
2) Ничто не нарушало размеренного течения его жизни.
3) Его жизнь текла размеренно и спокойно.
4) Врач рассказал, как протекает болезнь пациента
5) Процессы, протекающие в атмосфере...
7) Переговоры протекали трудно.

"Течь, протекать" is property of water, time, any process. Disease is  a process too.
...............

The word ВЯЛО has "distant relatives":  ВЯНУТЬ,  УВЯДАНИЕ.
An adverb "вяло" can only refer to the actions of an animate subject.

Он вяло улыбнулся — ОК

Он вяло махнул рукой — ОК

Камень катится вяло  — not OK

Ветер дует вяло — not OK

Река течет вяло — not OK

For some time nоw there is a phrase "вялотекущий процесс".
But it is only suitable for social or biological processes.

Comment: this does not answer the question